# MacOS App NSWindow over whole macOS UI including cursor

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I want my NSWindow over the macOS cursor. Is this possible? I managed to get the window above most of the UI, including Mission Control and the Menubar, but the cursor is still above the window. My code:

```
window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSScreen.main!.frame,
        styleMask: [.borderless],
        backing: .buffered, defer: true)
    window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    window.isOpaque = false
    window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
    window.level = NSWindow.Level.mainMenu + 1
    window.collectionBehavior = [NSWindow.CollectionBehavior.canJoinAllSpaces, .stationary, .ignoresCycle]
    window.minSize = NSSize(width: NSScreen.main!.frame.width, height: NSScreen.main!.frame.height)
    window.orderFront(nil)
    window.ignoresMouseEvents = true
```

Comment: Is this for a screen curtain curtain feature of a Remote Desktop app?

Comment: Why dont you simply hide the cursor inside your window?